# how to adb wait-for-device until the home screen shows up?

Tags: adb, stock-android, android-emulator

I need to unlock my screen using adb, and wait-for-device exits way too early(when the device is booting up), and screen unlock fails. Is there a way to detect that the home screen, so I can fire screen unlock then?

This is the command I am using to unlock screen -

```
adb wait-for-device shell input keyevent 82
```

Answer (score 30):

well wait-for-device, as you already realized only waits until the adb daemon properly started. This is already at init time. In order to check for a complete boot you cann ad to your script something like:

in pseudo:

1. wait-for-device
2. long as getprop sys.boot_completed != 1 sleep some seconds
   check getprop sys.boot_completed again
3. shell input keyevent 82

This should work.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

adb wait-for-device

A=$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')

while [ "$A" != "1" ]; do
        sleep 2
        A=$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')
done

adb shell input keyevent 82
```

This is not tested so be aware of potential mistakes

Comment: Please edit your answer to be easily readable. You have a valid answer, but a little clarity would help everyone.  Thanks

Comment: answer is now edited. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: good answer +1, now others will be able to follow it. Dont forget to add "*Always perform a backup*", for those accidental moments;)

Comment: I found that result of `getprop` had a carriage return after it, so changing the `adb` command to `$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')` did the trick. This is just trimming out the carriage return character.

Comment: @divided-by-zero please modify your answer to include the trimming mentioned by CoatedMoose. Umang please accept it as a answer as well.

Comment: trimming is added. thx CoatedMoose

Comment: How would you modify this if there's more than one device/emulator running?

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question and borderline off-topic but here is how to do it in a single line:

```
adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
adb wait-for-device shell <<ENDSCRIPT
echo -n "Waiting for device to boot "
echo "" > /data/local/tmp/zero
getprop dev.bootcomplete > /data/local/tmp/bootcomplete
while cmp /data/local/tmp/zero /data/local/tmp/bootcomplete; do 
{
    echo -n "."
    sleep 1
    getprop dev.bootcomplete > /data/local/tmp/bootcomplete
}; done
echo "Booted."
exit
ENDSCRIPT

echo "Waiting 30 secs for us to be really booted"
sleep 30

echo "Unlocking screen"
adb shell "input keyevent 82"
```